# Intercepting calls to Non-Existent Methods

Tags: ruby

Assuming the following incomplete code...

```
class Foo
  @an_array = []
  def method_catcher(this_var)
    unless self.method_defined? this_var
      if an_array.include?[this_var]
        p "Doing something with a fake method as if it were real." << this_var
      else 
        p "You attempted to call Foo with " << this_var << " this class will now self destruct, and you will be returned to entry."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I fire the method `method_catcher` on any method attempted on foo instead of it returning a `NoMethodError`?

Such as if I called

```
Foo.totally_not_a_declared_method_or_class_variable
```

so I could get either response depending on my array instead of erroring out?

Comment: *"How can I fire the method method_catcher"* -- name it [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) and Ruby does the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`#method_missing`](https://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing):

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts "Called method #{m}"
  end
end

Foo.new.asd
# Called method asd
```

Remember to define also [`respond_to_missing?`](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding)